# Change FreePBX Queue settings programmatically?

Tags: queue, asterisk, freepbx

Is there is anyway to change the settings(such as 'timeout') of a queue added by FreePBX?. I found No such options in Asterisk Manager (AMI) and CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can change in mysql in table queue_details. After that you should run /var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrive_conf to update config.

Comment: Thanks arheops, I will try it